# How do I sign an email message with a certificate and private key?

Tags: c#, winforms, ssl, smime, mimekit

So I'm trying to sign an email using an X509Certificate2 that has been selected by a user.  I've been trying to do this using MimeKit but the documentation for this appears to be old.

This is how they tell you to do this on the github page (found [here](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit))

```
using (var ctx = new MySecureMimeContext ()) {
    var certificate = GetJoeysX509Certificate ();
    var signer = new CmsSigner (certificate);
    signer.DigestAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithm.Sha1;

    message.Body = MultipartSigned.Create (ctx, signer, body);
}
```

The first issue I have is that the above is using

```
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate
```

and I am getting the certificate from X509Store() which uses

```
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
```

i.e.

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("My");

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

// bind to dropdownlist for user to select...

store.Close();
```

This suggests that I should be retrieving my list of certificates using some other method (one that I haven't been able to find any documentation for).

My second problem is that, CmsSigner requires a second argument (AsymmetricKeyParameter), not one, as shown in the example.

So my questions are:

- How do I get a list of certificates using MimeKit?
- How do I get an AsymmetricKeyParameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an `Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate` from a `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2`, you can use the following code snippet:

```
static bool TryGetCertificateAndPrivateKey (X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2, out Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate certificate, out AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey)
{
    if (x509Certificate2 == null || !x509Certificate.HasPrivateKey) {
        certificate = null;
        privateKey = null;
        return false;
    }

    var keyPair = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair (x509Certificate2.PrivateKey);
    certificate = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate (x509Certificate2);
    privateKey = keyPair.Private;

    return true;
}
```

I'll add a new CmsSigner constructor that takes an X509Certificate2 that does the conversion for you in the next release of MimeKit.

Comment: I had to make a couple of small modifications to make it compile i.e. !certifcate.HasPrivateKey became !x509Certificate2.HasPrivateKey and  privateKey = keyPair.PrivateKey; became privateKey = keyPair.Private;  But that seems to be what I need.

Comment: Oops, yea. I just updated my answer to fix those issues. Glad you got what you needed!